# Jenkins cannot run program sonar-runner

Tags: jenkins, sonar-runner

Installed:

Sonarqube 5.5

Sonar-runner 2.4 (http://dev.mamikon.net/installing-sonarqube-runner-on-ubuntu/)

When I try to run Jenkins with a simple project, this is the error I get:

> [test] $ sonar-runner -e
>   -Dsonar.host.url=http://*server_url*:9000/sonar/ -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
>
> SONAR ANALYSIS FAILED
>
> FATAL: command execution failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "sonar-runner" (in directory
>   "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test"): error=2, No such file or directory

It seems that jenkins cannot find the sonar-runner program.
But when I open the server with a terminal, and run sonar-runner, it analyzes the project.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Best guess: Jenkins has a sandboxed environment, you need to go into your jenkins config and add the sonar-runner location to Jenkin's path before it will know where to find it.  You'll need to figure out where the SonarRunner executable is installed.

Comment: @Tuffwer I somehow cannot set that variable. The sonar plugin from jenkins let met only configure the sonar server. (jenkins 2.5)

Comment: Did you follow all of the setup instructions on the [Sonar Qube for Jenkins setup wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AddingSonarQubeScanner)?

Comment: yes, i did follow they instructions.

Comment: Okay reading the error message, have you verified (by going to the directory in your terminal outside of Jenkins) that `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test` actually exists.  If you have the sonarqube job as a seperate jenkins job it may have it's own workspace and thus not have that test directory when it should be there.

Comment: yes, i can find the directory manual

Comment: i finaly got it fixed. turnes out i had to add environment variable in the /etc/profile file. it works now. thank you for help

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If it's information you haven' t been able to find here on SO you should consider adding the solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after hours of frustration, it turned out i had to add environment variable in the /etc/profile file.

> export SONAR_RUNNER_HOME=/opt/sonar-runner
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$SONAR_RUNNER_HOME/bin